# Calculator for volumes using mathermatical equations outputs strange results in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a calculator of volumes with integrals, by putting the equation. I did a test by using X - 6, with intervals 0 and 4, and looking at the final answer (finalfunction1, after it was multiplied by pi). The output is 603.18, it should be 217,81. By knowing what happened with that one i can fix the other. I am new to python so the code doesn't have the best lines of code.

Here is my work:

```
import math
import pyperclip
from sympy import integrate, sympify, symbols

pi = math.pi
x = symbols('x')
result = None

'''num_functions = input('How many functions (max 2): ')
if num_functions == 2:
    question = input('Do you want to find volume or just integrate?: ')
else:'''

question = input('Do you want to find volume or just integrate?: ')

# Definition of First function
function1 = list(input('First function: ').replace('^', '**'))
function1_list = []
for entry in function1:
    if entry == 'x':
        function1_list.append('*')
    function1_list.append(entry)
function1_str = ''.join(function1_list)
# print(function1_str)

# Definition of second function
function2 = list(input('Second function: ').replace('^', '**'))
function1_list = []
for entry in function2:
    if entry == 'x':
        function1_list.append('*')
    function1_list.append(entry)
function2_str = ''.join(function1_list)

try:
    # Definition of intervals for first function
    print('')
    print('Limits of first function')
    interval1_start = float(input('Lower limit: '))
    interval1_end = float(input('Upper limit: '))
    print('')
    function_not_integrated2 = sympify(function2_str)
    # Integration of function
    if question == 'volume' or 'Volume':
        print('yes')
        finalfunction1 = integrate(function_not_integrated2 ** 2, (x, interval1_start, interval1_end))
    else:
        finalfunction1 = integrate(function_not_integrated2, (x, interval1_start, interval1_end))
    # print("Sympy expression:", finalfunction1)

    # Definition of intervals for second function
    print('Limits of second function')
    interval2_start = float(input('Lower limit: '))
    interval2_end = float(input('Upper limit: '))
    print('')
    function_not_integrated2 = sympify(function2_str)
    if question == 'volume' or 'Volume':
        finalfunction2 = integrate(function_not_integrated2 ** 2, (x, interval2_start, interval2_end))
    else:
        finalfunction2 = integrate(function_not_integrated2 ** 2, (x, interval2_start, interval2_end))
    # print("Sympy expression:", funcionfinal)

except (ValueError, TypeError, SyntaxError) as e:
    print("Invalid input:", e)

finalfunction1 *= pi
finalfunction2 *= pi
print('Volume of first function: ', finalfunction1)
print('')
print('Second volume: ', finalfunction2)
print('')

total_volume = int(finalfunction1 - finalfunction2)
print('The resulting volume is: ', total_volume)

pyperclip.copy(total_volume)
print('')
print(total_volume, 'Has been copied to clipboard')
```

i tried x-6 with intervals 0 and 4 and get 603.18 where it should be 217. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need a continue in the `if entry == 'x': ` block, otherwise you're adding * twice, which is a power operator.